# Where can I find download link for 4.2.x installer and document.

Tags: marklogic

We are upgrading marklogic from 4.2.x to 8, before we are upgrading we are building greenfield installation for Marklogic 4.2.x.   So where can I find download link for 4.2.x installer and document.

Comment: Did you try google?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to reach out to MarkLogic support for this. You can no longer download it publicly.

HTH!